# "Dynamic" class loading

Tags: class, extjs, dynamic

I am new to computer programming and am currently studying the basics and fundamentals of writing great code. Every now and then I hear terms that I do not understand and cannot find suitable explanations for. The one I'm referring to currently is "dynamic".

I'm sure the term dynamic applies to many different areas of programming, but I'm not quite sure what it means.

Could anyone give a brief explanation and/or example?

Here is the context I read it in:

```
Dynamic Class Loading via Ext.require() - Sencha ExtJs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Dynamic" usually means something that is done at run time, rather than as part of the compilation or application build process. In the case you describe, it means loading code dynamically by executing `require()` at run time. The code that is loaded may change independently of the system that includes the call to `require()`. This technique is often used to load third-party libraries.

As you rightly point out, "dynamic" can have a myriad other meanings as well, so this is far from a comprehensive answer. It all depends on the context.

Comment: Good explanation, just to add a bit more here: In this case a string that is passed to the require() method will be interpreted as a full class name that needs to be loaded on the fly (dynamically) from a server (if it was not yet loaded).